# Is there a way to fetch instagram and Tiktok basic profiles using the email address?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I found an API reference that shows how to get the Instagram profile details using insta user_id or username but it looks like it doesn't work with email addresses. I'm trying to find a way to fetch the Instagram profile based on the email address.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery

Anyone has tried this before or know an API/way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no API for that (at least for Facebook.) You don't get access to any user profile data, just because you happen to know someone's email address. Users need to login to your app and grant it permission, before you get anything.

Answer (score 0):

2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fyassin.ni.5&_fb_noscript=1" />Log into Facebook<meta name="description" content="Log

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).